# tableview delete row problem

Tags: iphone

I have an tableview in my uiviewcontroller classes.. I have deleted row in tableview.
In the debugger console it shows an error is

0x939fe688  <+0024>  mov    0x20(%edx),%edi

My application terminated..

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: That is nowhere near sufficient for anyone to tell you what is going on. You need to provide more context, like a back trace, preferably with symbols.

Comment: What Louis said, plus try looking down the stack a bit in the debugger to see what function is crashing, then look at the code in that function that breaks. It should give you an idea where to start, at least. (My gut feeling is that you're trying to access an object, like your table view cell, that's been `dealloc`ed - make sure that's not the case.)

Comment: please show the code where you delete a row.

Answer (score 0):

This messaege is displayed in log console

Assertion failed: (cache->size >= g->size), function evict_glyph_entry_from_cache, file Fonts/CGFontCache.c, line 836

Comment: You should update your question with this information, as well as providing other information, such as a stack trace.